# FileZilla file transfers time out at 100% — is the transfer successful?

Tags: filezilla

Only recently larger file transfers have started to time out in FileZilla for me, but the transfers are still considered as "successful", not "failed". FileZilla skips the transfer (`Status:  File transfer skipped`) — does this mean that the download is complete or not? What does reaching 100% effectively mean?

[The issue is likely network-related](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration#Timeouts_on_large_files). I'm not asking what may cause this, my inquiry is solely related to the file integrity. I don't really have the means to verify hashes for every downloaded on both my server and home computer.

Comment: The files I verified the checksum for matched (over 20).

Comment: also see: https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/5536

Comment: If you have recently updated FileZilla which didn't have the same problem in the same circumstnaces., you might try an older version.